# What is the meaning of the quotation below?

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotes, quotations

> “Perfection is a trifle dull. It is not the least of life’s ironies
>   that this, which we all aim at, is better not quite achieved.” — W. Somerset Maugham

Comment: This looks more like literary criticism than a matter of the language used, and may be closed. What aspects of the grammar or vocabulary, exactly, do you have difficulty with?

Comment: I don't understand it's meaning actually!

Comment: A greater irony than Maugham's assertion that "[perfection] is better not quite achieved" is that to know this for a fact required Maugham to be perfect as well as conscious of his perfection, regardless of how brief that perfection was. He's merely being a cetacean expelling seawater from his cerebral blowhole.

Comment: Brings to mind Robert Browning's, “Ah, but a man's reach should exceed his grasp,
Or what's a heaven for?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is saying that even though people strive to be perfect, actually being perfect is not interesting. The irony is that *the pursuit of perfection* does not imply that *achieving perfection* is the goal.

For me, this rings similar to Emerson's quote: "Life is a journey, not a destination."